# Reference Material UI SelectField component from onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form with a lot of SelectField components in it (15+) - I'm trying to avoid having multiple change handler functions, but I'm struggling to find out how to reference the specific select that triggered the change so I can update the state accordingly.

I've tried adding an id, ref, and every possible solution that I've seen asked before but nothing is working.

```
<SelectField value={this.state.selectedFramework} onChange={this.handleChange} style={style}>
    <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="Please select..." />
    {this.props.frameworks.map(this.renderMenuItem)}
</SelectField>
```

My change handler is as follows:

```
handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
    this.setState({selectedFramework: value});
};
```

But this obviously can't be used by multiple selectfield components as the state key is hard coded. I need to reference the select that triggered the change so I know which state key to update.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create an arrow function and pass in the index of the select field:

```
{this.state.selectFields.map((v, i) => {
    <SelectField value={v} onChange={(e, _, v) => this.handleChange(e, i, v)} style={style}>
        <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="Please select..." />
        {this.props.frameworks.map(this.renderMenuItem)}
    </SelectField>
}

handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
    const selectFields = this.state.selectFields.slice();
    selectFields[index] = value;
    this.setState({selectFields});
};
```